# UTM to Latitude/Longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I've coded up Karney's transformations from UTM to latitude/longitude coordinates. My work however requires me to know if this conversion is in geocentric or geodetic latitude. I have not been able to find this information online. Does anyone know if Karney's "Transverse Mercator with an accuracy of a few nanometers" is conversions to geocentric or geodetic latitude? I have an educated guess, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Almost certainly geodetic, but the person to answer would be http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/3613/cffk - @cffk

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the latitude is the geodetic latitude.  Nearly always when the term "latitude" is used without any qualifier, the geodetic (or geographic) latitude is meant.